# Proving that the Chebyshev approximation can be written as a linear program

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Given the Chebyshev (or minimax) approximation problem:

$\min_\limits{x} ||Ax-b||_\infty, \\
\text{subject to } x \succeq 0$

I want to write it as a linear program in the following manner:

$\min_\limits{y, t} t, \\
\text{subject to } a^T_{i}y -t \leq b_i \forall i=1,...k, \\
-a^T_{i}y -t \leq -b_i \forall i=1,...k, \\
y \succeq 0$

My initial approach is to take $y=x$ and $t = ||Ax-b||_\infty$ so that I can show that every feasible solution $x$ of the Chebyshev optimization problem has a feasible solution  $(y, t)$ in the linear program, and vice versa. How do I proceed from here, or correct my approach to solving this?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Besides feasibility, you also need to show that the objective values agree.